# Pandas read_csv is not parsing date and time

Tags: python, pandas, read-csv

I have a csv file which looks like this

```
Study ID,CG_Arrival_Date/Time,Arrival_Date,Arrival_Time
2,1/1/2011 0:03,1/1/2011,0:03:00
3,1/1/2011 0:53,1/1/2011,0:53:00
```

I wanted to parse arrival date and arrival time, so I worte this on Google Colab.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/SM_AI_Data.csv', index_col=['Study ID'],parse_dates=[['Arrival Date','Arrival Time']])
df.head()
```

The columns get combined fine, but its data type is still object.

How can I change the code so that it works?

Please see the details above.

Comment: Post the actual CSV text, not as an HTML table. Actual text can be used to reproduce the problem with `df.read_csv(StringIO(thtaText),...)`

Comment: BTW `Arrival Time` is *not* a date. Did you mean `Arrival Date/Time` perhaps?

Comment: Since Arrival Date/Time has not the correct format, I'd rather combine arrival date and arrival time

Comment: I have parsed Arrival Date/Time, too. It still shows up as object

Comment: The original csv looks like this
Study ID,Arrival_Date/Time,Arrival_Date,Arrival_Time
2,1/1/2011 0:03,1/1/2011,0:03:00
3,1/1/2011 0:53,1/1/2011,0:53:00

Comment: Post the string in the question itself. I see `Arrival_Time 2,1/1/2011 0:03` which *can't* be correct

Comment: I think you are seeing ID right next to the Arrival_Time

Comment: That's why you need to add the text to the question, not the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce any problem if I specify the columns correctly. I use the indexes here because I'm too lazy to use the names :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv_text="""
Study ID,Arrival_Date/Time,Arrival_Date,Arrival_Time 
2,1/1/2011 0:03,1/1/2011,0:03:00
3,1/1/2011 0:53,1/1/2011,0:53:00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_text), index_col=['Study ID'],parse_dates=[1,2])
df.dtypes
```

This produces

```
Arrival_Date/Time    datetime64[ns]
Arrival_Date         datetime64[ns]
Arrival_Time                 object
```

The contents are:

```
    Arrival_Date/Time   Arrival_Date    Arrival_Time
Study ID            
2   2011-01-01 00:03:00 2011-01-01  0:03:00
3   2011-01-01 00:53:00 2011-01-01  0:53:00
```

The Date and Time columns can be combined too :

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv_text="""
Study ID,Arrival_Date/Time,Arrival_Date,Arrival_Time 
2,1/1/2011 0:03,1/1/2011,0:03:00
3,1/1/2011 0:53,1/1/2011,0:53:00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_text), index_col=['Study ID'],parse_dates=[[2,3],1])
df.dtypes
```

The contents are

```
    Arrival_Date_Arrival_Time   Arrival_Date/Time
Study ID        
2   2011-01-01 00:03:00 2011-01-01 00:03:00
3   2011-01-01 00:53:00 2011-01-01 00:53:00
```

It's not possible to tell what the format is from the values. DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY? The correct format can be specified by setting the `dayfirst` parameter to `True` or False`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think I put too much in one go. Pandas cannot handle 15,000 lines at once.

Comment: It can. 15K lines is very little data. It's quite possible there's invalid text in one of those lines though

Comment: Turned out it was the invalid data such as n/a that prevented it from running correctly. I have run 15k rows succssfully now :)

Comment: Does it mean we never can parse a time with a format of H:M as a datetime object and it has to be a combination of date time? @PanagiotisKanavos